# remove save button on a particular page

Tags: forms

I am creating a form which consists of 3 tabs. In the first tab form submit is by clicking on save button of type submit,in the second tab the submit is by jQuery, in the third tab the submit is by clicking on save button of type submit. My problem is I want the save button to appear on only two tabs i.e., only on first and third tab. I don't want the save button to appear on second tab bcoz that second tab form I submit using jquery.

How can I remove save button in second tab?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
 if (window.location.pathname == '/recruiterForm/2') {
      jQuery('input#edit-submit').hide();
      }
});
```

I have solved this problem using jquery. I have used **window.location.pathname**. This property returns the pathname of current page. If pathname is equal to the required url then I am hiding the save button by using the save button id. This solution works for me.